# ng serve doesn't work anymore after locking pc?

Tags: angular

I made the mistake to lock my pc and letting my Angular Project run, everytime I forget to quit my running Angular project I get the following error in my console when unlocking my pc:

```
ERROR in src/app/app.component.html:13:32 - error TS2339: Property 'myDataArray' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.

13 <table mat-table [dataSource]="myDataArray">
                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:5:16
    5   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.
src/app/app.component.html:13:18 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'dataSource' since it isn't a known property of 'table'.

13 <table mat-table [dataSource]="myDataArray">
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:5:16
    5   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.
```

This happened in multiple instances and I can't really figure out why, I already tried restarting my pc and analyzing the error but I haven't had any success yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is clearly an issue to variables which are not set.
Check your app.component.html for the specified "mat-table" from the error message.
Then check if the variable "myDataArray" is actually an instance member-variable of app.component.ts, and if it is set properly (array of displayed elements).